# PHPSESSID VS sennding user/pass in android

Tags: php, android, session

I'm new to Android/Java programming and I came across an issue where I have to use PHP session to keep the user logged in (persistant login), this has a set of methods form using httpclient cookie or using SharedPreferences and it made think of this solution instead of using session,

1- Login the user with backend with HTTPs, this will happen only the first time the user login, the app I'm working on requires one time login and no logout mechanism. the user name and password will be sent by SMS after installing the app.

2- If user exist save the save the user/pass(could be token here) in SharedPreferences

3- Whenever the user needs something from the backend send the user/pass over HTTPs and the backend will reply if the user/pass(could be token here) is correct.

My question is, do you think the overhead of checking the user/pass or token with every request is a bad idea?

The reason I'm asking this is that PHP session ID use the same method by checking the file that has the session variables which looks like the same overhead caused by checking the user/pass or token against DB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much diference, what I actually do is create a token which contains the user identifier encripted with a salt, that way you can just verify credentials at the login and then use that token during the session, you can then easily retrieve the user on the PHP and do whatever needs to be done. I woulnd't recommend passing the user/pass every time, more query complexity and risk of credentials steal. About the session... I've never messed with it for a REST based service called by a mobile device client just because I don't see the need, guess it depends on what does the service do.

Comment: Are you using sessions or just sending the token with every request?

Comment: With every request, with session you would end having to add it's cookie in every request either way.